# Is there a way to toggle a selected item on the renderItem SelectList in react-native?

Tags: react-native, onclick, switch-statement, toggle, selectlist

I would like to toggle only one switch in the render item I am creating. So far when I toggle, all buttons toggle and I understand it's because I'm passing the same state to the value of all my switches but I don't know how to target just one

I have tried using other native components but none seem to be able to work like an input where I can pass an event and target it

```js
state = {
    containers: dataYay,
    selectedContainers: [],
    checked: false
}

containerSelected(value, item, index) {
    console.log(item.Nbr, item.CtrId)
    this.setState({ checked: value })
}
```

```js
renderItem={({ item, index, section }) => {
return (
    <Block padding={[10, 15, 20, 15]} color='#EFF8FF' margin={[0, 0, 1, 0]} row center middle key={index}>
        <Block styles={styles.ContainerAssign} flex={0.3}>
            <Switch
                style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: .8 }, { scaleY: .8 }] }}
                value={this.state.checked} //  i would like to check just one of these 
                testID={index}
                onValueChange={(value) => this.containerSelected(value, item, index)}
            />
        </Block>

        <Block styles={styles.ContainerInfo} padding={[0, 5, 0, 0]}>
            <Text style={styles.ContainerInfoText}>
                <Text style={styles.ContainerInfoTitle}> Container ID:              </Text>  {item.CtrId}
            </Text>
            ... // code would be too long to displa
        </Block>

        <Button
            ... // code would be too long to display
        </Button>
    </Block>
)
}}
```

What I need help with is to find a way to pass the switch toggle to the current item on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Make your item to state component through React.Component class.

For example,

```
class Item extend React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: false,
  }

  render() {
    return() {
      <Block padding={[10, 15, 20, 15]} color='#EFF8FF' margin={[0, 0, 1, 0]} row center middle key={index}>
        <Block styles={styles.ContainerAssign} flex={0.3}>
            <Switch
                style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: .8 }, { scaleY: .8 }] }}
                value={this.state.checked} //  i would like to check just one of these 
                testID={index}
                onValueChange={(value) => this.containerSelected(value, item, index)}
            />
        </Block>

        <Block styles={styles.ContainerInfo} padding={[0, 5, 0, 0]}>
            <Text style={styles.ContainerInfoText}>
                <Text style={styles.ContainerInfoTitle}> Container ID:              </Text>  {item.CtrId}
            </Text>
            ... // code would be too long to displa
        </Block>

        <Button
            ... // code would be too long to display
        </Button>
    </Block>
    }
  }
}
```

And use this item in your renderItem of parent.

```
renderItem = {({item}) => <Item item={item}/>}
```

## Why?

`this.state.checked` was applied to renderItem's component. Thus, every renderItem component was using the same state called from `this.state.checked`. That is why it affects to all items. And I resolve this to use independent states in Item component.

Comment: It worked but could you please explain how come this worked ?

Comment: @RaphaelL I added answer. And you can find more information from offical site. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html